# OpenGL - sine and cosine waves in jogl (JAVA)

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, trigonometry

I'm trying to code a sine and a cosine wave to be displayed on my panel. I am trying this in my EventListener class by creating a method drawCurves().

CurvesGLEventListener:

```
package firstAttempt;

import javax.media.opengl.GL;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU;

/**
 * For now we will focus only two of the GLEventListeners init() and display().
 */
public class CurvesGLEventListener implements GLEventListener {

    /**
     * Interface to the GLU library.
     */
    private GLU glu;

    /**
     * Take care of initialization here.
     */
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL gl = drawable.getGL();
        glu = new GLU();

        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        gl.glViewport(0, 0, 900, 550);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        glu.gluOrtho2D(0.0, 900.0, 0.0, 550.0);
    }

    /**
     * Take care of drawing here.
     */
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

        GL gl = drawable.getGL();

        drawCurves();

    }

    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width,
            int height) {
    }

    public void displayChanged(GLAutoDrawable drawable,
            boolean modeChanged, boolean deviceChanged) {
    }
    private void drawCurves() {
            /**
             * Here is where I need to implement the method
             **/
    }
}
```

I've been advised that, with this viewpoint, I should plot my wave using:

```
(x, (Math.sin(x/60.0)*100.0))
(x, (Math.cos(x/60.0)*100.0))
```

Could you help me implement this method? What seems like a good idea is that the method takes an argument (e.g. int whichOne) to declare which wave is drawn each time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not going to write the code for you, but [this](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Harmonic_partials_on_strings.svg), seems to have a passable method using Bezier splines. Of course it is in Lua, but you should be able to transpose it into java methods.